# CSS for Horizontal Button

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to make my button horizontal but always not work
I have tried display:block, display:inline, adjust padding & margin

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="text/html">


<title>Rumah Yatim dan Dlu'afa | Jazirah Indonesia I</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="banner_box">

<span>
<img src="images/head.png" height="150px" class="banner_img" alt="logo">
</span>

<p1>
RUMAH TAHFIDZ
</p1>
<br>
<p2>
YATIM PIATU DAN DLU'AFA
<p2>

<ul class="navbutton">
<li><a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Beranda">BERANDA</a></li>
<li><a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Acara">ACARA</a></li>
<li><a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Info">INFO</a></li>
<li><a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Donasi">DONASI</a></li>
<li><a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Profil">PROFIL</a></li>
</ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css

```
/* Html */

html {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

/* Background */

body {
    background:url(images/body.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

/* Banner */

.banner_box {
    width:480px;
    height:180px;
    padding:5px;
    border:4px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#063;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.banner_img {
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
}

p1 {
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

p2 {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Button */

.myButton {
    background-color:#44c767;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}

.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

ul.navbutton {
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul.navbutton li {
    display:inline;
}
```

and this is preview
https://db.tt/uxAm95A2

help my practice
thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid `p1` and `p2` are not valid HTML elements.

Comment: how to correct them? I want to create with different font size

Comment: though it looks good :P

Comment: _"how to correct them? I want to create with different font size"_. Use CSS. `font-size`.

Comment: sadaf2605: not good, my button not work correctly, i want to make horizontal button

Comment: for your navbar to be inline just change the following code `ul.navbutton {position: absolute;list-style-type: none;width: 100%;}`

Comment: j08691: I change p1 with h1 or I add class to p or something else?

Comment: Kawinesh SK: okay I will try, thanks

Comment: @kiki.kiko add class to `p` element or use `span` instead with `display: block` btw you can't put five buttons in line within `480px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link, if this is what you want:-
http://jsfiddle.net/s7d8D/

```
 ul.navbutton {position: relative;width: 100%;}
```

Comment: requires 15 reputations :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to you guys :D :D :D
I have edited my html and css

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="text/html">


<title>Rumah Yatim dan Dlu'afa | Jazirah Indonesia I</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="banner_box">

<span>
<img src="images/head.png" height="150px" class="banner_img" alt="logo">
</span>

<span class="p1">
RUMAH TAHFIDZ
</span>
<span class="p2">
YATIM PIATU DAN DLU'AFA
</span>

<ul class="navbutton">
<li class="navbutton1">
<a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Beranda">BERANDA</a>
</li>
<li class="navbutton2">
<a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Acara">ACARA</a>
</li>
</li>
<li class="navbutton5">
<a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Profil">PROFIL</a>
</li>
<li class="navbutton4">
<a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Donasi">DONASI</a>
</li>
<li class="navbutton3">
<a href="x" class="myButton" alt="Info">INFO</a>
</ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css

```
/* Html */

html {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

/* Background */

body {
    background:url(images/body.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

/* Banner */

.banner_box {
    width:480px;
    height:186px;
    padding:5px;
    border:4px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#063;
    border-radius:35px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.banner_img {
    padding-right:10px;
}

.p1 {
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
    position:relative;
    top:-128px;
    text-align:center;
}

.p2 {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    position:relative;
    top:-129px;
    left:190px;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Button */

.myButton {
    background-color:#44c767;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}

.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}

.myButton:active {
    position:fixed;
    top:1px;
}

.navbutton {
    position:inline;
    width:100%;
}

.navbutton1 {
    position:relative;
    top:-38px;
    left:-30px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navbutton2 {
    position:relative;
    top:-58px;
    left:80px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navbutton3 {
    position:relative;
    top:-118px;
    left:170px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navbutton4 {
    position:relative;
    top:-98px;
    left:240px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.navbutton5 {
    position:relative;
    top:-78px;
    left:330px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

works well on firefox, safari and chrome :D :D

preview

https://db.tt/oLPp1Bza